# How to check if string-number with decimals is double or integer?

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer, double

I'm reading values from a `.csv` file and there are numbers in which are stored in the format `#.##`, i.e. the number `4` is stored as `4.00`.

Now I need to check if the nuber is an integer or a double value. Depending on the type I need to format the string in the right way.

I made two checks to validate the value but it never passes the integer-check.

```java
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    // only got here if we didn't return false
    return true;
}

public static boolean isDecimal(String s) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    // only got here if we didn't return false
    return true;
}
```

Is there a easy way how I can check this?

Comment: Unclear whether you're talking about the value or the format being integer. Are you wanting to treat strings ending in .00 as integers? or only strings with no decimal point at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```java
public boolean isInteger(String s) {
    boolean result;
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        if ((d == Math.floor(d)) && !Double.isInfinite(d)) {
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

```java
public boolean isDecimal(String s) {
    boolean result;
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        if (d != Math.floor(d)) {
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
private static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    return Double.parseDouble(s) % 1 == 0;
}
```